# Changing the message in onblur event upon condition for all input fields in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, onblur

I have more than 20 input fields with onblur defined in all the fields with its respective message in it. Upon condition, i wanted to change the message.

Following is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <label for="fullname1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">  
        <span id="w7_E">Full Name</span>
        <span id="w7_B">Poskod</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname1" name="fullname" onkeyup="checkKeyUp(this);" onblur="checkOnBlur(this,'Please Enter Your fullname');" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="fullname1"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <label for="postcode1" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> 
        <span id="w20_E">Postcode</span>
        <span id="w20_B">Poskod</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postcode1" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" onkeyup="checkKeyUp(this);fetch_state(this);" onblur="checkOnBlur(this,'Please Enter Your Postcode');">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <label for="state1" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> 
        <span id="w21_E">State</span>
        <span id="w21_B">Negeri</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state1" name="state" placeholder="State" onkeyup="checkKeyUp(this);" onblur="checkOnBlur(this,'Please Enter Your State');">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
```

My Jquery code:

```
function checkOnBlur(me, message) {
        var e_id = $(me).attr('name');
        var element_name= (this.name);
        if (!(me.val()).length) {
            var exist = document.getElementById(e_id + '_e');
            var langID='<%=session.getAttribute("language_sel")%>';
            if (exist == null) {
                var htmlString = "";
                if(langID == 'B') {     
                    if (element_name == "fullname") {
                        message = "Sila masukkan nama penuh penama";
                    }

                    if (element_name == "postcode") {
                        message = "Sila masukkan poskod";
                    }
                    if (element_name == "state") {
                        message = "Sila masukkan negeri";
                    }
                }
                htmlString += '<label id=' + e_id + '_e' + '  ' + 'class="error">' + message + '</label>';
                $(htmlString).insertAfter("#" + e_id);
                $('#' + e_id).focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

If langID = "B", message in jquery code should appear.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arf, you mixed jsp and javascript and it doesn't work because jsp is server-side and js is client-side. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19708010/7131047

Comment: Thanks Fefux. But atleast if i get the actual logic in Jquery, it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: A solution could be to generate `<script>var language="B"</script>` tag in java and append it in your jsp. But this is not very elegant and use global variable which become quiclky a nightmare to debug.

Comment: Replace var langID='<%=session.getAttribute("language_sel")%>';  with var langID = 'B'. In this case, the message has to be updated but its not.

Comment: replace htmlString by `htmlString += '<label id="' + e_id + '_e" class="error">' + message + '</label>';`

Comment: And `"#" + e_id` doesn't exist